# Recognizing speech at 1bit quantise depth?

Tags: acoustics, signal-processing

i found on german wikipedia an audio example of **1 bit depth quantising**, where the speech still can be recognized. how is it possible if at 1 bit depth we have just two values: "signal" and "no-signal"?. here is the examle: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/43/Ampl1rp.ogg

Comment: This seems more like Computer Science SE material rather than physics.

Answer (score 2):

A 1 bit depth quantised signal still contains more than one bit of information. The signal level varies from moment to moment, and this provides extra information.

In the case of speech we tend to recognise the rhythmicity and structure as speech even if we cannot make out individual words. Some [formant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formant) sounds may be recognisable if they get the signal stream to flip from 0 to 1 and back again at the same frequency: we tend to recognise voice sounds by their peak formant frequencies, so again this helps recognizing the signal as speech.

Comment: thank you veryuch for answer! but i dont understand how it can contains more levels than two. look at the wave analysis of that example- there are some waves, which are placed outside of quantising levels: https://i.imgur.com/fEMhvyO.png

Comment: but the example above is described as 1bit depth audio (from wikipedia). shouldn't it be pure square signal? or do i get that noise because of interpolation?

Answer (score 2):

1-bit quantization involves *sign-only* sampling, which can be done at fantastic rates, well over 10^9 samples per second.  For purposes of speech recognition, frequencies over 6 kHz are irrelevant.  If a low-frequency signal plus wideband noise is subjected to 1-bit quantization, nonlinear phenomena can sometimes interfere with extraction, but they don’t always do that.  Consider the following cases:

(1) A low-frequency signal of high amplitude plus wideband (think *white*) noise of low amplitude.  The noise can throw off the recorded sign of the signal whenever the signal crosses zero, but this sort of error averages to zero.  A bigger problem is that sinusoidal signals get converted to square waves, so there are nasty *intermods* -- beats and harmonics.  In the simple case of square waves, the harmonics contain only 20% of the power.  Ratios of amplitudes will be distorted in mixtures of overtones, possibly preventing the identification of vowels distinguished by ratios of overtones in the formant regions of the spectrum.

(2) A low-frequency signal of low amplitude plus wideband gaussian noise of high amplitude.  The weak signal will register only when the noise happens to be smaller, but that happens often enough to allow extraction with minimal distortion by intermods.  There will be 2 dB of nonlinear suppression relative to many-bit quantization.  Ultimately, a high sampling rate saves the day.  Averaging *N* uncorrelated samples will enhance the signal-to-noise ratio by a factor of *N*.